# Getting time zone from current geo location of user without using Time Zone API

Tags: java, android, google-location-services

Consider the following:

```
LocationCallback mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            List<Location> locationList = locationResult.getLocations();
            if (locationList.size() > 0) {
                //The last location in the list is the newest
                Location location = locationList.get(locationList.size() - 1);
            }
        }
    };
```

If I try to get my current time zone using:

```
long time = location.getTime();
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(new Date(time));
TimeZone timeZone = calendar.getTimeZone();
```

The time zone returned is the one associated with my current **running device** and NOT **my current location**. Because of the current logic, the user can manually change his/her current time zone through the device settings --> Date & Time --> Disable automatic time zone.

Is it possible to get the current time zone based on the user geo location using the Google Play Services Location API and not any other API?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need the local time zone?

- If the user has their time zone set elsewhere, why ignore their preference? If the user has overridden the automatic time zone feature, it is because they want to see moments presented in a particular time zone.
- If recording the current moment, generally speaking, you should be recording the current value in UTC without regard for any time zone.

Also, you are using terrible troublesome date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

To capture the current moment, use UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

For presentation to the user, use the JVM’s current default time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

If crucially important, confirm with the user. Or at least display in the user-interface the time zone you are using.

The two variables `instant` and `zdt` represent the same simultaneous moment, the same point on the timeline, but with a different wall-clock time.

To input an appointment or event in the future, collect a date, a time-of-day, and a zone. Assemble them into a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 13 , 30  ) ;
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z ) ;
```

To compare to the current moment, get an `Instant`, adjusting to UTC.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

Get current moment.

```
Instant now = Instant.now() ;
```

Compare.

```
if( instant.isBefore( now ) ) {
    … reject their input
}
```

So you can see that the user’s physical location should be irrelevant to your handling of date-time values and time lobes.

The fact that you asked your Question makes me suspect there is some aspect of date-time handling that you do not fully understand. Date-time handling is trick business. So clarify your Question or respond with a Comment if you think I’ve missed your point.

Comment: The business logic is the following: the more users interact with the app by creating events in their calendars, the more they get rewarded with points. With that in mind, we decided to use the current time from the server and not from the device, otherwise they will have the possibility of creating events in past and get rewarded for that, which is something that we do not want. Because of the time logic implemented, I decided to try using the time zone from location in maps instead of the one in the device, because it could be manually changed. Let me know if you need me to explain further.

Comment: @RedM Again, there is no need to ignore their preference of time zone. If the issue is going back in time before the current moment, you can always check that. Take whatever date, time, and zone the user submits, produce a `ZonedDateTime`, call `toInstant` as shown in my Answer, compare to `Instant.now()` on your server. No need to care about their geolocation. .